# Global CORS configuration not working in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cors

So I tried to add a global CORS configuration in my Spring Boot app. I can make it work when I autorize all origins (by putting a '*' with CorsRegistry.allowedOrigins) but when I try to specify http://localhost:8080 for exemple, it doesn't work.

My Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/svc")
    public ResponseEntity<String> method(@RequestParam(required = false) String id) {
    //some code
    }
```

My Configuration :

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {


    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080")
                .allowedMethods("POST", "GET",  "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE")
                ;
            }
        };
    }
```

So that doesn't work as intended. But when I put

```
registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*")
```

It works when I call http://localhost:8080/api/svc?id=999 from the client.

Any idea on what I'm missing here ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you've a copy/past issue, and I suppose that your server is running in localhost on port 8080. You should be aware that `.allowedOrigins` should contains client origins, so change :

`registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080")` to `registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:[client_port]")`.

where **client_port** is your client port.

---

**EDIT**

IF you want to get the client ip, you can bind HttpServletRequest to your method (this is only for getting the client address, once done you can remove the binding) :

```
@GetMapping("/client/ip")
public ResponseEntity<String> getClientIp(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String clientAddress = "";
    if (Objects.nonNull(request)) {
        clientAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
        if (Objects.nonNull(request) || "".equals(remoteAddr)) {
            clientAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
        }
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(clientAddress);
}
```

Comment: Oh that might be it. I call the API from a javascript file wich I open in firefox. Do you know how I can check the client port?

Comment: you can inspect it from your browser ( inspect element > go to network > click the http request then you can see the host header )

Comment: Or else you can just set the allowedOrigins to "*"and see

Comment: I've checked the request header in firefox and the host is localhost:8080.And yes, using "*" works but I would like to be able to restrict the allowed origins

Comment: @Raikyn Oh sorry it's my mistake, you can see my edit to know how to get client address

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi Thanks a lot, I finally managed to track it down with your solution :)